# Prevent duplicates when insert by SQLXMLBULKLOADLib

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, sqlxml

I am wondering if is there a way to prevent insert of duplicate rows while we use [SQLXMLBULKLOADLib](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sqlxml-annotated-xsd-schemas-xpath-queries/sqlxml-4-0-net-framework-support-using-bulk-load?view=sql-server-ver15)? I've tried to add `UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX` to the SQL table, however insert by `SQLXMLBulkLoad4Class` fails.

So my code looks likes this

```
SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.SQLXMLBulkLoad4Class objBL = new SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.SQLXMLBulkLoad4Class();  
objBL.ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb;server=server;database=databaseName;integrated security=SSPI";  
objBL.ErrorLogFile = "error.xml";  
objBL.KeepIdentity = false;  
objBL.Execute ("schema.xml","data.xml");
```

My xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
   <row>
      <BICYCLE_NUM>624</BICYCLE_NUM>
      <BICYCLE_ORDER>1</BICYCLE_ORDER>      
   </row>
   <row>
      <BICYCLE_NUM>623</BICYCLE_NUM>
      <BICYCLE_ORDER>2</BICYCLE_ORDER>      
   </row>
   <row>
      <BICYCLE_NUM>681</BICYCLE_NUM>
      <BICYCLE_ORDER>3</BICYCLE_ORDER>      
   </row>
   <row>
      <BICYCLE_NUM>625</BICYCLE_NUM>
      <BICYCLE_ORDER>4</BICYCLE_ORDER>      
   </row>
   <row>
      <BICYCLE_NUM>680</BICYCLE_NUM>
      <BICYCLE_ORDER>5</BICYCLE_ORDER>      
   </row>
</foo>
```

And  XSD looks like this:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
        xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mapping-schema">  
<xsd:element name="row" sql:relation="BICYCLE"   
                        sql:key-fields="BICYCLE_NUM">  
    <xsd:complexType> 
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="BICYCLE_NUM"   type="xsd:integer" />   
            <xsd:element name="BICYCLE_ORDER"   type="xsd:integer" />  
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

SQL table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE BICYCLE (  
         BICYCLE_NUM   INT ,  
         BICYCLE_ORDER INT 
GO  

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_BICYCLE_NUM__BICYCLE_ORDER
   ON Wagon (BICYCLE_NUM, BICYCLE_ORDER);
```

I've tried to set `CheckConstraints = true`, nevertheless the result is the same

```
SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.SQLXMLBulkLoad4Class objBL = new SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.SQLXMLBulkLoad4Class
            {
                ConnectionString = connectionString,
                ErrorLogFile = "error.xml",
                KeepIdentity = true,
                CheckConstraints = true
            };
```

My question is how can I prevent insert of duplicates using SQLXMLBULKLOADLib?

Comment: SQLXML is very old, and you should avoid using it in new projects.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thanks for the response. However, what alternatives can we use?

Comment: Use SqlBulkCopy, or send the XML to SQL Server and parse it using  .nodes() or OPENXML. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/use-the-value-and-nodes-methods-with-openxml?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft If we use `SqlBulkCopy`, then we should parse `xml` files by `C#` and then insert parsed data through `SqlBulkCopy`?

Comment: Yes.  Parse the XML with XDocument or a combination on an XmlReader and XDocument if the document is very large.  Then load a DataTable, or if very large, implemnet an IDataReader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exploring `SQLXMLBulkLoad4Class`, `IgnoreDuplicateKeys` property was found. So we can use `IgnoreDuplicateKeys` property:

```
SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.SQLXMLBulkLoad4Class objBL = new SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.SQLXMLBulkLoad4Class
{
    ConnectionString = connectionString,
    ErrorLogFile = "error.xml",
    ISQLXMLBulkLoad_IgnoreDuplicateKeys = true,
    IgnoreDuplicateKeys = true
};
objBL.Execute(xsdScheme, xmlFileName);
```

In addition, `CONSTRAINT` should be used, not `UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX`:

```
CREATE TABLE BICYCLE 
(  
      BICYCLE_NUM   INT
    , BICYCLE_ORDER INT
    , CONSTRAINT PK_BICYCLENUM_BICYCLEORDER PRIMARY KEY 
        NONCLUSTERED (BICYCLE_NUM, BICYCLE_ORDER)    
)
GO
```